# Run a tracert continually for period of time

Tags: networking, ping, traceroute, latency

I have a site where network speed and specific network related activities become very slow. I want to run a tracert from one of the PC's onsite to, say, a file server or print server located at our head office and see if and where the dropouts/latency issues are. Is there a way I can tracert between 2 devices constantly back and forth for a specific amount of time to see where the issues are?

Comment: No, ``traceroute`` also shows times.

Comment: ping shows me if drops somewhere however not where on the hop the issue is, i think Wireshark maybe of some use however not 100% of how to use it's tracert ability

Comment: Look into a program called mtr (or winmtr on windows). It is sort of a hybrid between ping and traceroute.

Comment: `pathping` is probably a better choice as it will show exactly where the delays/losses occur. Remember to run it at each end as reverse routing may be different.

Comment: i looked into winmtr was getting 'unable to get raw socket' errors

Answer (score 2):

A quick solution would be to use a self-calling batch script which displays the date and time before doing a tracert

For example

```
 @echo off
echo Doing tracert at %date%, %time% >> pinger.txt
tracert 8.8.8.8 >> pinger.txt
pinger.bat
```

This would keep a batch window open which continuously repeats displaying the date and time and doing a tracert, writing everything to a log file (pinger.txt) until the window is closed.

The resulting log will appear like so:

```
Doing tracert at 2019-03-14,  2:02:11.87 

Tracing route to google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     2 ms     5 ms     8 ms  x.x.x.x
  2    18 ms    17 ms    17 ms  x.x.x.1 
  3    17 ms    19 ms    19 ms  rc1st-tge0-8-0-0-1.vc.x.net [64.59.149.181] 
  4    24 ms    25 ms    23 ms  rc2wt-be50-1.wa.x.net [66.163.70.106] 
  5    21 ms    27 ms    23 ms  x.14.x.90 
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  7    21 ms    23 ms    21 ms  x.125.253.x
  8    21 ms    51 ms    19 ms  209.x.254.69 
  9    23 ms    27 ms    19 ms  google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8] 

Trace complete.
Doing tracert at 2019-03-14,  2:02:58.44 

Tracing route to google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     4 ms     4 ms     2 ms  x.x.x.x
  2    17 ms    15 ms    15 ms  x.x.x.x 
  3    16 ms    21 ms    21 ms  rc1st-x-8-0-0-1.vc.x.net [64.59.149.181] 
  4    20 ms    21 ms    23 ms  rc2wt-x-1.wa.x.net [66.163.70.106] 
  5    22 ms    21 ms    21 ms  72.x.242.90 
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  7    22 ms    19 ms    23 ms  x.125.253.66 
  8    21 ms    25 ms    27 ms  209.85.x.69 
  9    24 ms    25 ms    19 ms  google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8]
```

Note: IP addresses have been censored with 'x's for anonymity.

Sources:

[Date/Time Display & Write to Log File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39715936/add-timestamp-to-log-lines-from-batch-output)

[Infinite Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32339190/infinite-loop-windows-batch-file)

Answer (score 0):

Some of the smartest people researching latency/slowness problems on the Internet are the people who've collaborated to identify and fix [bufferbloat](https://www.bufferbloat.net/projects/). Along the way they created a tool called [Flent](https://flent.org), and a specific Flent test called Realtime Response Under Load (RRUL), that's great for discovering bufferbloat-related latency problems between any two hosts you control on the Internet or any IP network.

I'd recommend you look into running a Flent RRUL test between the two sites in question.